TypeScript drizzle errors for a column that has been defined
I'm using Drizzle in order to interface with a postgres DB and a query to insert into the "stop" table randomly errors
Query
  await db.insert(stopTable).values({
    name: stopDetails.name,
    latitude: stopDetails.latitude,
    longitude: stopDetails.longitude,
  });

Schema
export const stopTable = pgTable("stop", {
  id: uuid("id").primaryKey().defaultRandom(),
  name: text("name").notNull(),
  latitude: decimal("latitude").notNull(),
  longitude: decimal("longitude").notNull(),
});

with the TS error being
TS Error
(And yes other schemas exist and work perfectly fine with the exact same query)
Already tried pushing the schema, and checking if the problem is with the decimal type. Also all the imports are from "drizzle-orm/pg-core" so that's not it either
